# How can I revise my schema design to support a group by query with a field?

Tags: influxdb

I have a simple set of records that I wish to filter by domain, count and group by urls. These are both fields:

```
time                | domain      | url
------------------- | ----------- | ----
1500163196000000000 | www.foo.com | /bar
1500163197000000000 | www.foo.com | /bar
1500163198000000000 | www.foo.com | /baz
```

When I made a query to group the URL counts, it seems to have grouped all records:

```
SELECT count(url) FROM logs GROUP BY url

name: logs
tags: url=
time count
---- -----
0    3
```

How can I revise my schema design to support this group by query? If I turned url and domain into a tag, then that means I have no value and can't insert the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anything that needs to be searched on (filters, group by etc), it needs to be a tag (indexed field).

At least one field is required by the DB when writing and it defaults to using a field called `value` if none is set. So you can set `value=0` as your single field if you do not actually want to query it.